# ¿Cómo buscar muchas coincidencias en una tabla?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo una tabla llamada `users` ésta misma se relaciona con otra tabla llamada `aplicaciones`. Lo que quiero hacer es buscar todos los cerca de 740 usuarios en la tabla users que coincidan con algún campo de la tabla `aplicaciones`

Por ejemplo:

```
Usuario: mauricio
aplicación: xbox_store

____________________
USUARIO | Aplicación|
========|===========|
mauricio| xbox_store|
```

El detalle es que con éste tipo de busqueda tendré que estar ingresando el nombre de usuario como parámetro, por cada usuario!!
**hay alguna manera de poder utilizar su `id` como filtro?** ya que todos los usuarios tienen un `id`, como llave primaria.

Cabe destacar que:
Ambas tablas (`usuarios` y `aplicaciones`) estan unidas por una tabla pivote, en la cual se encuentran los id de `usuarios` y `aplicaciones`.

Éste es mi query, sin embargo arroja datos erroneos, ya que sólo junta una tabla con otra:

```
SELECT aplicacion.nombreapp, usuarios.usuid AS usuid FROM aplicacion, usuarios;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entiende que hay una relación entre las 3 tablas. Se puede usar la siguiente estructura:

```
SELECT usuario.id_usuario, app.id_app, app.info
FROM usuario, usu_app, 
app WHERE usuario.id_usuario = usu_app.id_usuario AND usu_app.id_app = app.id_app
AND app.info = 'TextoComun'
```

Answer (score 0):

para eso necesitaras hacer uso de los joins, si tienes una tabla pivote podras utilizarla para enlazar las aplicaciones y los usuarios. La consulta seria mas o menos así

```
select a.nombreapp, u.usuid
    FROM USUARIO U
    INNER JOIN APLICACIONUSUARIO AU ON AU.USUID=U.ID
    INNER JOIN APLICACION A ON AU.APPID = A.ID.
```

De esta menera espero haber respondido tu duda. Te dejo un enlace sobre el uso de los JOINS de cualquier manera.

http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2016/01/uso-de-join-en-sql-server.html